# hide element if express is returning empty values

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, hbs

I'm creating app on **nodejs** and **express**. I'm getting json data from endpoint and rendering it on page according to values that I'm getting.

Problem is that, If I get null or undefined value from json data, how will I hide the whole element.

here's my code :

```
        var obj = JSON.parse(body)

        res.render("index", {
          name : `${obj.data.name}`,
          uname : `${obj.data.username}`,

          bio : `${obj.data.bio}`,
          location : `${obj.data.location}`,
          link : `${obj.data.website}`
```

rendering values on hbs template page :

```
<div class="ml-9 w-full mt-1 px-3 mb-5 inline-block">
        <div class="inline-block mr-5">
            <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt text-lg opacity-75 inline"></i>
            <p  class="text-xl inline ml-2 bio">{{location}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="inline-block mx-5">
            <i class="fas fa-link text-lg opacity-75 inline"></i>
            <p  class="text-xl inline ml-2 link text-blue-400">{{link}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="inline-block mx-5">
            <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt text-lg opacity-75 inline"></i>
            <p  class="text-xl inline ml-2 bio">{{join}}</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

Now, If I get null or undefined location or bio, how will I hide the whole div.

[image: check sample output]

Comment: https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/node+js+check+if+null+or+undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use IF condition inside the hbs template.

```
{{#if location}}
<p  class="text-xl inline ml-2 bio">{{location}}</p>
{{/if}}
```

It will print the value only if it presents.

Answer (score 1):

You can use build-in helper [if](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#if).

Comment: No problem. Accept this answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Use {{#if}} . I guess it will solve your problem